# insserv: warning: script 'S99runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides

Tags: init.d

I am unable to install a new software or upgrade the existing ones. I have been getting insserv warning ([see here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25513779/))

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It was the script 'runlcactivator' in /etc/init.d which was creating the problem.

I delted it by executing the command - `sudo rm /etc/init.d/runlcactivator` after being told by another friend in this forum and it worked!